# Can't get new line to work in python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

This is the code that i'm currently using to try to get a new line. Sadly it just rewrites the first line in the program. What is going on? If you can help I will be very thankful.

```
import itertools
import string
import sys, os, cmd

from datetime import datetime
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
passwordstried = 0


numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',]
symbols = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","'",'"',":",";","+","=","[","{","]","}","<",",",">",".","?","/","|","\"","~","`"]
lowercaseletters = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]
uppercaseletters = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]


stuff = lowercaseletters + uppercaseletters + numbers + symbols


if (input("Do you have the length of the password?") == 'y'):
    lengthstartingvalue = int(input("Password length: "))
else:
    lengthstartingvalue = 1


starttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(starttime)


starttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
for L in range(lengthstartingvalue, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(stuff, L):
        #print(subset)


        password = ''.join(subset)
        print(password)

        file = open("generatedpasswords.txt","w")
        file.write(str(password) + '\n')

        passwordstried = passwordstried + 1
    if (L>lengthstartingvalue+1):
        break

endtime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
elapsed = datetime.strptime(endtime, FMT) - datetime.strptime(starttime, FMT)
print ('Time elapsed:',elapsed)
print ('Passwords tried:',passwordstried)
file.close()
```

Comment: You have to be more specific, please post code that we can run to see the issue you are having.

Comment: Well the code you have posted works just fine....There should be some other mistake

Comment: Added all the code. I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem that you are reopening the same file inside of the loop...

```
file = open("generatedpasswords.txt","w")
for L in range(lengthstartingvalue, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(stuff, L):
        #print(subset)


        password = ''.join(subset)
        print(password)


        file.write(str(password) + '\n')




        passwordstried = passwordstried + 1
    if (L>lengthstartingvalue+1):
        break
```

This will reopen the same file again and again and will write the last password to the file ultimately
In case you want to append  current password and don't want to lose your previous data then you can use `file = open("generatedpasswords.txt","a")` inside the for loop....

Comment: I need to wait 53 secs. :P